# InvalidOperationException when using azure cache locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-caching

I get an InvalidOperationException when trying to create an azure cache instance locally (exception and code shown below). The code is being run from a console application. It works fine when I run it in a worker role in the azure emulator.

Is it possible to use azure cache without running it in the emulator?

> {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: role discovery data is unavailable
>   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.get_Roles()

Config

```
  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="mycache.cache.windows.net">
      <autoDiscover
        isEnabled="true"
        identifier="mycache.cache.windows.net" />
      <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="false">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="[mytoken]=" />
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
```

Code:

```
        bool autoDiscover = true;
        string identifier = "foo";

        var cacheFactoryConfiguration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration
        {               
            AutoDiscoverProperty = new DataCacheAutoDiscoverProperty(autoDiscover, identifier),
            TransportProperties = new DataCacheTransportProperties { MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue },
            IsCompressionEnabled = true,
            MaxConnectionsToServer = 3
        };

        var dataCacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(cacheFactoryConfiguration);
```

Comment: Which Azure Cache option are you using (service, in-role [dedicated], in-role [co-located], or shared)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not with the AutoDiscovery feature. AutoDiscovery is a feature for in-role caching and requires an Azure RoleEnvironment (hence the error you are getting).

```
// Cache client configured by settings in application configuration file.
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration config = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration("mycache.cache.windows.net");
DataCacheFactory cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(config);
DataCache defaultCache = cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();    

// Put and retrieve a test object from the default cache.
defaultCache.Put("testkey", "testobject");
string strObject = (string)defaultCache.Get("testkey");
```

Also **NOTE** - I wouldn't do any development on Azure Shared cache - the service is being retired in 2014 - see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/